# jQuery.ajax to *only* retrieve the status code but not retrieve/download the entire document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, http-status-codes

I have an app that is using `jQuery.ajax` to poll a resource to find out if it exists. (There's a service in the background that is generating the resource).  When the resource is no longer giving a status of 404, my app redirects to that resource for viewing.  My question is... can I get the status *without* downloading the entire contents of the document?  If the PDF it's polling for is very large I'm afraid it'll just be inefficient to get a status of 200 and download the doc via jquery, and then discard it and redirect to the document in question.

Here's what I'm doing (coffeescript):

```
class PDFPoller

  constructor: (@url) ->

  pollForPDF: ->
    @timeout = setTimeout(@poll, 3000)

  poll: =>
    jQuery.ajax(@url, complete: @verifyPDF)

  verifyPDF: (jqXHR, textStatus) =>
    console.log jqXHR.status
    if jqXHR.status != 404
      window.location = @url
    else
      @pollForPDF()

  @isGeneratingPDF: ->
    $(".js_pdf_gen_notice").length > 0

  @events: =>
    if @isGeneratingPDF()
      poller = new PDFPoller($(".js_pdf_gen_notice").data('url'))
      poller.pollForPDF()

$(document).on 'ready', ->
  PDFPoller.events()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get just the status code, but you can ask for just the HTTP headers.

Use the `HEAD` method. You can then check the status of the jqXHR object.

```
jQuery.ajax("/", { type: "HEAD"}).done(
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hmm, I like this idea but the `jQuery.ajax` documentation says "The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers."  What's the browser support for "HEAD" when used here?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#History_and_support) says *IE7 and later*.

Comment: Yep this appears to be working great for me :)  I'm making the request to Amazon S3, so I had to enable the HEAD method in my CORS configuration and also use a signed HEAD url as opposed to the signed GET url I had been using.  Working great though!

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any callback for once headers received from the request, but on the server side couldn't you have a script that checks if the file exists on the server and then returns JSON if it does or not?